# Could not parse mapping document from resource hibernate.hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, ojdbc

we have a customer who has a new oracle database 19c and wants to migrate all applications to directly connect with oracle database 19c. The applications are currently connected to 19c via a proxy (12c oracle database).

Using ojdbc8.jar, jdk 1.8.341 and updating the connection string in hibernate.cfg.xml to try to connect to the new 19c database, I encountered the error: **org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource hibernate.hbm.xml**

The application is deployed in Tomcat 6. Hibernate.cfg.xml with ojdbc is located inside tomcat lib folder. hibernate.hbm.xml is located within the application

```
Hibernate.cfg.xml (12c)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=1.1.1.1)(PORT=1523))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=1.1.1.1)(PORT=1523)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = service.com.sg)))</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">userpassword</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <!--
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        -->
        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">15</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">15</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
        <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

```
Hibernate.cfg.xml (19c)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1521)
(host=host.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=service.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_dn_match=no)))</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">userpassword</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <!--
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        -->
        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">15</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">15</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
        <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

```
hibernate.hbm.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.avaya.ept.cdg.beans.AdhocMessage" table="IVR_ADHOC_MESSAGE">
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="functionality" type="string" length="100" />
            <key-property name="msgLanguage" column="MSG_Language" type="string" length="10" />
        </composite-id>

        <property name="status"  not-null="true" type="string" length="10" />
        <property name="wavFile" column="WAVEFILE" not-null="false" type="string" length="100" />
        <property name="interrupt" type="string" not-null="false" length="10" />
        <property name="startDateTime" column="Start_Date_Time" not-null="false"  type="timestamp" />
        <property name="endDateTime" column="End_Date_Time" not-null="false"  type="timestamp"/>        
        <property name="lastChangedBy" type="string" column="Last_Changed_By" not-null="false"  length="100" />
        <property name="lastChangedOn" type="timestamp" column="Last_Changed_On" not-null="false" />
        <property name="modifyReason" column="modify_Reason" type="string" not-null="false"  length="100" />
        <property name="ivrLanguage" column="IVR_LANGUAGE" type="string" not-null="false"  length="10" />
        <property name="waveFileList" column="WAVEFILELIST" type="string" not-null="false"  length="105" />
    </class>

    <class name="com.avaya.ept.cdg.beans.CallHistory" table="IVR_CALL_HISTORY">

        <id name="ucid" type="string" length="50"/>
        
        <property name="startDateTime" column="Start_Date_Time" not-null="true" type="timestamp" />
        <property name="endDateTime" column="End_Date_Time" not-null="true" type="timestamp" />
        <property name="callDuration" column="CALL_DUR" not-null="true" type="integer"/>
        <property name="cliEntered" type="string" length="3" not-null="true" column="CLI_ENTERED"/>
        <property name="clid" type="string" not-null="false" length="30" />
        <property name="dnis" type="string" not-null="false" length="30" />
        <property name="lastMenuID" column="LAST_MENU_ID" type="string" not-null="false" length="10" />
        <property name="custLanguage" column="CUST_LANGUAGE" type="string" not-null="false"  length="10" />
        <property name="customerName" column="CUSTOMER_NAME" type="string" not-null="false"  length="50" />
        <property name="priority" type="string" not-null="false"  length="10" />
        <property name="duplicateCallFlag" column="DUPLICATE_CALL_FLAG" type="string" not-null="false"  length="10" />
        <property name="bookingStatus" column="BOOKING_STATUS" type="string" not-null="false" length="10" />
        <property name="bookingId" column="BOOKING_ID" type="string" not-null="false"  length="20" />
        <property name="jobId" column="JOB_ID" type="string" not-null="false" length="20" />
        <property name="taxiNumber" column="taxi_Number" type="string" not-null="false"  length="20" />
        <property name="transferedCallFlag" column="TRANSFERRED_CALL_FLAG" type="string" not-null="false" length="2" />
        <property name="transferCount" column="TRANSFER_COUNT" type="string" not-null="false" length="2" />
        <property name="transferReason" column="TRANSFER_REASON" type="string" not-null="false" length="10" />
        <property name="answeringAgentId" column="ANSWERING_AGENT_ID" type="string" not-null="false" length="10" />
        <property name="answeringAgentSkill" column="ANSWERING_AGENT_SKILL" type="string" not-null="false" length="20" />
        <property name="queueTime" column="QUEUETIME" type="string" not-null="false"  length="10" />
        <property name="lastMenu1" column="LASTMENU_1" type="string" not-null="false" length="50" />
        <property name="lastMenu2" column="LASTMENU_2" type="string" not-null="false" length="50" />
        <property name="lastMenu3" column="LASTMENU_3" type="string" not-null="false" length="50" />
        <property name="lastMenu4" column="LASTMENU_4" type="string" not-null="false" length="50" />
        
        <bag name="hostTransaction" cascade="all" inverse="true" table="IVR_HOST_TRANSACTIONS" lazy="true">
            <key column="ucid"  not-null="true" />
            <one-to-many class="com.avaya.ept.cdg.beans.HostTransactions" />
        </bag>
    </class>

    <class name="com.avaya.ept.cdg.beans.HostTransactions" table="IVR_HOST_TRANSACTIONS" >
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="ucid" type="string"  length="50"/>
            <key-property name="requestDateTime" column="Request_Date_Time" type="timestamp" />
        </composite-id>
            
        <property name="icdMessageId" column="ICD_MSG_ID" type="string" not-null="true" length="20" />
        <property name="transactionName" column="transaction_Name" type="string" not-null="true" length="50" />
        <property name="responseDateTime" column="Response_Date_Time" type="timestamp" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="requestMessage" column="req_message" type="string" not-null="false" length="2500" />
        <property name="responseMessage" column="res_Message" type="string" not-null="false" length="3500" />
    </class>

    <class name="com.avaya.ept.cdg.beans.MenuDescription" table="IVR_MENU_DESC">    
        <id name="imdMenuId" column="IMD_MENU_ID" type="string" length="10"/>
        
        <property name="vdn" not-null="true" type="string" length="10" />
        <property name="imdMenuName" column="imd_Menu_Name" not-null="true" type="string" length="100" />
        <property name="lastChangedON" column="last_Changed_ON" type="timestamp" not-null="false"/>
        <property name="lastChangedBY" column="last_Changed_BY" type="string" length="100" />
    </class>
    
    <class name="com.avaya.ept.cdg.beans.Usage" table="IVR_USAGE">
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="ucid" type="string" length="50"/>
            <key-property name="iuOrder" type="java.lang.Integer" column="IU_ORDER"/>
        </composite-id>
        <property name="menuId" column="MENU_ID" not-null="false" type="string" length="10" />
        <property name="iuDateTime" column="Iu_Date_Time" not-null="true" type="timestamp"/>
        <property name="iuRemarks" column="Iu_Remarks" not-null="true" type="string" length="50" />
    </class>

    <class name="com.avaya.ept.cdg.beans.TTSSMS" table="IVR_TTS_SMS">
        <id name="flag"  column="Flag" type="string" length="10"/>
    </class>
    
    <class name="com.avaya.ept.cdg.beans.HostMapping" table="IVR_HOST_MAPPING">
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="functionality" column="FUNCTIONALITY" type="string" length="50"/>
            <key-property name="hostValue" column="HOST_VALUE" type="string" length="10"/>
        </composite-id>
        
        <property name="msgLanguage" column="MSG_Language" type="string" length="10" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="wavfile" type="string" length="100" not-null="false"/>
        <property name="status" type="string" length="10" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="msgDescription" column="MSG_Description" type="string" length="100" not-null="false"/>
        <property name="lastChangedBy" column="Last_Changed_By" type="string" length="100" not-null="false"/>
        <property name="lastChangedOn" column="Last_Changed_On" type="string" not-null="false"/>        
    </class>
    
    <class name="com.avaya.ept.cdg.beans.CallOutRequest" table="IVR_CALLOUT_REQUEST">
        <id name="requestId" column="REQ_ID" type="int">
            <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">IVR_CALLOUT_REQ_ID_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="jobId" column="JOB_ID" type="string" length="20" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="taxiId" column="TAXI_ID" type="string" length="20" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="addressId" column="ADDRESS_ID" type="string" length="20" not-null="false"/>
        <property name="requestDateTime" column="REQUEST_DATE_TIME" type="timestamp"  not-null="true"/>
        <property name="callBackNumber" column="CALLBACK_NUMBER" type="string" length="30" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="callOutResult" column="CALLOUT_RESULT" type="string" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="ucid"  type="string" not-null="false"/> 
        <property name="initiatorId" column="INITIATOR_ID" type="string" length="10" not-null="false"/>
    </class>
    
    <class name="com.avaya.ept.cdg.beans.IvrDnisMapping" table="IVR_DNIS_MAPPING" lazy="false"> 
        <id name="vdn" column="VDN" type="string" length="10"/>     
        <property name="hotlineNumber" column="HOTLINE_NUMBER" not-null="true" type="string" length="20" />
        <property name="hotlineDescription" column="HOTLINE_DESCRIPTION" not-null="true" type="string" length="30" />
    </class>
    
    <class name="com.avaya.ept.cdg.beans.AutoparkFailover" table="AUTOPARKFAILOVER" lazy="false">   
        <id name="ucid2" column="UCID2" type="string" length="50"/>
        <property name="apDateTime" column="AP_DATE_TIME" not-null="false"  type="timestamp" />     
        <property name="ucid1" column="UCID1" not-null="true" type="string" length="50" />
        <property name="clid" column="CLID" not-null="true" type="string" length="20" />
        <property name="bookingId" column="BOOKING_ID" not-null="true" type="string" length="20" />
        <property name="jobId" column="JOB_ID" not-null="true" type="string" length="20" />
        <property name="numOfTaxis" column="NUM_OF_TAXIS" not-null="false" type="string" length="20" />
        <property name="langPref" column="LANG_PREF" not-null="false" type="string" length="20" />
        <property name="parkType" column="PARKTYPE" not-null="false" type="string" length="50" />
        <property name="notifyBySms" column="NOTIFY_BY_SMS" not-null="false" type="string" length="20" />
        <property name="queuePriority" column="QUEUE_PRIORITY" not-null="false" type="string" length="10" />
        <property name="transferReason" column="TRANSFER_REASON" not-null="false" type="string" length="10" />
        <property name="blacklisted" column="BLACKLISTED" not-null="false" type="string" length="10" />
        <property name="hotLineNumber" column="HOTLINE_NUMBER" not-null="false" type="string" length="10" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

```
Error Stack Trace

08/06/2023 14:56:27:636  INFO - Session Info is Null. Creating... 
08/06/2023 14:56:27:636  INFO - Config Path: D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib\hibernate.cfg.xml
08/06/2023 14:56:27:658 ERROR - Error creating Session Factory org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource hibernate.hbm.xml
08/06/2023 14:56:27:658 ERROR -  : Stack Trace: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:671)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1679)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1647)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1626)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1600)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1554)
com.avaya.ept.cdg.service.config.HibernateSessionFactory.buildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:48)
com.avaya.ept.cdg.service.config.HibernateSessionFactory.getSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:35)
com.avaya.ept.cdg.service.impl.DBServiceImpl.doEndCallProcess(DBServiceImpl.java:194)
com.avaya.ept.cdg.Util.doPostCallProcess(Util.java:326)
flow.CDG_EndCallProcess.requestBegin(CDG_EndCallProcess.java:70)
com.avaya.sce.runtime.AppServlet.processRequest(AppServlet.java:81)
com.avaya.sce.runtime.SCEServlet.requestHandler(SCEServlet.java:282)
com.avaya.sce.runtime.SCEServlet.doGet(SCEServlet.java:181)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
com.avaya.sce.runtime.SCEServlet.forward(SCEServlet.java:1303)
com.avaya.sce.runtime.Data.handleRequest(Data.java:153)
com.avaya.sce.runtime.AppServlet.processRequest(AppServlet.java:96)
com.avaya.sce.runtime.SCEServlet.requestHandler(SCEServlet.java:282)
com.avaya.sce.runtime.SCEServlet.doGet(SCEServlet.java:181)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

08/06/2023 14:56:27:658 ERROR -  : Cause: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping com.avaya.ept.cdg.beans.AdhocMessage
08/06/2023 14:56:27:659  INFO - Session Info Created.
```

```
Code to reach out to hibernate

//Calling To The DNIS Mapping Table for The DB To Get The HotLine Number
String dnis = mySession.getVariableField(IProjectVariables.SESSION,IProjectVariables.SESSION_FIELD_DNIS).getStringValue();
if(null != dnis && !CDG_JMS_Constants.EMPTY.equalsIgnoreCase(dnis.trim())){
try
{
    DBServiceImpl dbServiceImpl = new DBServiceImpl(dBInfo);
    IvrDnisMapping ivrDnisMapping =  dbServiceImpl.findIvrDnisMappingForVdn(dnis);
        if(null != ivrDnisMapping.getHotlineNumber()){
            dnis = ivrDnisMapping.getHotlineNumber();
    }
    trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_DEBUG, "HotLine Number Recieved From The DB Look Up : "+dnis);
                    
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    if(mySession.isDDTraceEnabled())
{
        trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_DEBUG, "Exception Occured while Performing DB LookUp For HotLine Number :" + e.getMessage());
                        Util.doAlarmEvent(mySession, "WARNING", "Exception Occured while Performing DB LookUp For HotLine Number :" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }               
            }
```

```
DBServiceImpl

@Override
    public IvrDnisMapping findIvrDnisMappingForVdn(String vdn) {
        logger.debug(sessionId + " : *****Loading IvrDnisMapping for VDN: "+vdn+" *****");
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession(dbInfo); 
            return (IvrDnisMapping) session.load(IvrDnisMapping.class, vdn);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            logger.error(sessionId + " : Exception occured while Loading IvrDnisMapping for VDN: "+vdn+". "+ e.getMessage());
            logger.error(sessionId + " : Stack Trace: "+ e.getStackTrace());
            logger.error(sessionId + " : Cause: "+ e.getCause());
            return null;
        }finally{
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
            logger.debug(sessionId + " : *****Loading IvrDnisMapping for VDN: "+vdn+" *****");
        }
    }
```

```
HibernateSessionFactory

package com.avaya.ept.cdg.service.config;

import java.io.File;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.avaya.ept.cdg.beans.DBInfo;

/**
 * Author:jerald.a
 *
 */

/**
 * Configures and provides access to Hibernate sessions
 */
public class HibernateSessionFactory {
    
    private static Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    private static org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private HibernateSessionFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * @param dbInfo
     * @return
     * @throws HibernateException
     */
    public static Session getSession(DBInfo dbInfo) throws HibernateException {
            if (sessionFactory == null) {
                dbInfo.getLogger().info("Session Info is Null. Creating... ");
                buildSessionFactory(dbInfo);
            }
            dbInfo.getLogger().info("Session Info Created. ");
            return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    /**
     * Build hibernate session factory
     * 
     */
    private static void buildSessionFactory(DBInfo dbInfo) {
        try {
            dbInfo.getLogger().info("Config Path: "+dbInfo.getConfigPath());
            configuration.configure(new File(dbInfo.getConfigPath()));
            dbInfo.getLogger().info("Hibernate Configuration configured.");
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
            dbInfo.getLogger().info("Session Built.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            dbInfo.getLogger().error("Error creating Session Factory "+ e);
            
            String stackTrace = "";
            
            for (StackTraceElement element : e.getStackTrace())
                stackTrace += element.toString() + "\n";
            
            dbInfo.getLogger().error(" : Stack Trace: "+ stackTrace);
            dbInfo.getLogger().error(" : Cause: "+ e.getCause());
        }
    }

}
```

Base on the current setup, I have 2 connection strings, one that connects to 12c database and another to 19c database directly.

Below are the cases which I have tried.

1. ojdbc6/jre6u21/12c connection string - works
2. ojdbc6/jre6u21/19c connection string - cannot open connection (which I understand 19c only works with ojdbc8)
3. ojdbc8/jdk8u341/12c connection string - works
4. ojdbc8/jdk8u341/12c connection string - org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource hibernate.hdb.xml

I have read several forum posts which relates to parsing exception but it seems it does not apply in this scenario. I am puzzled why I am getting parsing exception when it is working with 12c connection but not 19c connection.

Could the hibernate jar files contribute to the issue? The versions used are as below:

1. hibernate-3.5.2.Final.jar
2. hibernate-c3p0-3.6.3.Final.jar

There are no issues using SQL Developer to connect to both 12c and 19c connection string.